# Linux Box using PHP writing file to Windows Server Web Share

Tags: php, windows, linux, fwrite

We have a bunch of linuix and windows servers.

On my windows desktop I can see all the shares.

Using PHP I'm attempting to write a file to a directory on a windows share using the UNC path.

```
//ServerShare/directory/file.txt
```

Using `fwrite` says it successfully wrote the file but the file never exists on the server.

Using `opendir` function says the directory isn't accessible.

This is the source pretty simple.

```
 $file_name = "\\SERVER2\Share\CPI\data.txt";

if (!$handle = fopen($file_name, 'w')) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($file_name)";
     exit;
}

// Write $somecontent to our opened file.
$somecontent = "this is a test";
if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
}

echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($file_name)";

fclose($handle);
```

Any thoughts on what types of permissions need to be set to let a linux box write files to a windows box?

Comment: fyi, the $file_name is like this 

$file_name = "\\\\SERVER2\\Share\\CPI_INFO\\data.txt";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be mounting the fileshare to a local directory:

```
mount -f smbfs //user@server2/Share/CPI/Data.txt /media/share
```

Then access `/media/share/Share/CPI/Data.txt` from your PHP script.

PHP needs to authenticate to the share, even if it is public, and using `fopen` or `opendir` does not do this.

Comment: If I get our network admin to mount the fileshare locally to the linux box, I'll still need to Authenticate?  What would you suggest I use to write data files out to the windows server instead of fopen, opendir, fwrite?

Comment: It is possible for the sysadmin to mount the share with credentials automatically. I would suggest writing the files locally and then copying them over, install ssh or ftp on the windows server.